# Problema muy extraño con New Date en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, date, datetime

me dirijo a ustedes a ver si alguien puede orientarme que es lo que sucede con este codigo...

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

---------------------- java ---------------------

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");

Date datofecha1 = new Date (time1);
String datotexto1 = formatter.format(datofecha1);
System.out.println(datotexto1);
```

---

el long de time1, lo estoy trayendo de mi base de datos cloud firebase, es un item number 1597081737457

Ese codigo deberia de imprirme:

```
I/System.out: 10.08.2020, 13:48:57
```

pero me imprime

```
I/System.out: 31.12.1969, 20:00:00
```

SI cambio el long en mi base da datos para que me imprima otra fecha, siempre me imprime, 31 de diciembre del año 1969, una total locura (sea cual sea el long que le coloque).

Como dato curioso si coloco el long directo al codigo de esta manera:

---------------------- java ---------------------

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");

Date datofecha1 = new Date (1597081737457L);
String datotexto1 = formatter.format(datofecha1);
System.out.println(datotexto1);
```

---

De la siguiente manera si me imprime perfecto la fecha

Como dato curioso en la base de datos, solo puedo colocar numero para el long, no puedo colocarle la L final, que se debe de colocar para el long, y de verdad en esto estoy atrapado intentando que me imprima la fecha del long usado, y no esa fecha del 31 de diciembre que siempre me coloca, espero hayan entendido, de antemano gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías decir lo que es el valor `1597081737457`? ¿Es una marca del tiempo? Si es una fecha, ¿por qué se almacena así y no como una fecha?

Comment: Hola Cedano, si es una fecha, se crea con: new Date().getTime();

Comment: ¿Por qué no creas la fecha en el contexto donde obtienes el dato desde Firebase? Existe el método `.toDate()` para convertir una marca del tiempo Firebase a un objeto `Date`, supongamos que en la lectura tu dato de llama `mTimeStamp`, bastaría con hacer algo así: `Date mDate=mTimeStamp.toDate();` y listo.

Comment: Vale Cedano, voy a intentar probar ese metodo, a ver que tal funciona, y te estoy escribiendo

Comment: Veo que obtienes valores incorrectos incluso  Java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null" @aAaDesigner , esto se debe porque algunos valores que obtienes de Firebase no son correctos, te sugiero imprimirlos para que afirmar lo que comento, agregue respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si en la base de datos el valor esta en formato `long` u otro formato de numero entero (si es un tipo `int` o de menos bits puede perderse datos).
De otra manera el valor puede estar recibiendose en otro formato (puede ser String?).

Si el valor es un numero, prueba obligando el tipo long

```
Date datofecha1 = new Date ((long)time1);
```

O si es `String`, hacer la conversion a long

```
Date datofecha1 = new Date (Long.parseLong(time1));
```

Comment: Hola Igor, gracias por responder, esta en la base de datos en formato long, aunque sabes que la base de datos no acepta long como tal sino number, asi que esta en formato numerico. la primera sugerencia, ya la habia probado y me da igual la fecha del 31 de diciembre, la segunda sugerencia voy a probarla, y te escribo, voy a cambiar en la base de datos el item a tipo string y pruebo a ver

Comment: Hola igor, realice la segunda sugerencia, y me da un Java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"

Comment: Indica que el valor de time1 es `null`, por lo tanto de alguna manera no esta llegando un valor de fecha (fecha vacia). Revisa los datos de origen, si hay casos con valores de fecha vacio. En ese caso puedes entregar un String vacio si `(time1==null)`

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al valor en milisegundos que tienes 1597081737457 la fecha debería ser "Mon 10 August 2020 12:48:57" o con el formato que estas realizando que es  10.08.2020, 13:48:57

Realizando una conversión del valor obtenido en Firebase a `Long` debe ser suficiente, no deberías tener problema en mostrar la fecha correcta, si se esta mostrando una fecha incorrecta es porque el valor de `time1` es un tipo diferente a `Long`:

En cuanto a el error :

> Java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"

ocurre porque hay valores que estas obteniendo desde firebase los cuales no pueden ser convertidos a Long, en este caso null, para estos casos te recomiendo validar.

Realiza lo siguiente:

```
try{
    Date datofecha1 = new Date (Long.parseLong(time1));
    String datotexto1 = formatter.format(datofecha1);
    System.out.println(datotexto1);
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    System.out.println("El valor no se puede convertir a Long.");
}
```

Para lo anterior si el valor de `time1` es 1597081737457 , Tendrías como valor de salida :

```
10.08.2020, 13:48:57
```

Comment: Hola Jorge, he resuelto mi problema moviendo todo ese codigo dentro addOnSucessLitener, donde recibo los datos en tiempo real de la base de datos, al moverlo alli listo, funciono perfecto, antes tenia el codigo en el oncreate, Super raro, pero era algo con la bese de datos

Comment: @aAaDesigner ví que tenias el error: "Java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"", me parece que los valores no se estaban leyendo correctamente en ocasiones por eso obtenias otra fecha, como comento, tú codigo debió funcionar sin problema.

Comment: SI era como que llegaba vacio de la base de datos, unos de los item, por alli lei que metiera todo donde recibia lo datos y listo, asi cero errores, todo marcha perfecto, gracias por tu ayuda